# What are some alternatives to Worldbuilding Stack Exchange that are “brainstorming sites”?

Tags: discussion

I will admit, I’m not in the best mood after [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/251859/97864), so I’m going to keep this streamlined to avoid me losing my cool and turning this question into a rant full of… choice words. Either way, I’m asking because, personally, I started asking questions on Worldbuilding Stack Exchange solely for brainstorming. So, what alternatives are there to Worldbuilding Stack Exchange that *do* allow you to ask questions with an exceptional scope of valid answers?

Comment: I can understand your frustration finding out that the site isn't suitable for your purpose a whole year after joining. We're trying to figure out how to better communicate how this site works to newcomers to prevent whiplash like you experienced. Would you be willing to answer some questions about what drew you to WB and what you remember from your onboarding?

Comment: I don’t really remember why I chose stack exchange. For me, a year’s way too long ago to remember those details precisely.

Comment: Not enough for a full-fledged answer, but you have a small list of forums at the bottom of [the worldbuilding resources list](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/143607/80336). You'll have to check how well they fit your needs however, I haven't checked myself their rules.

Comment: @Tortliena -- This isn't Main. This is essentially the answer, since it contains links to worldbuilding Q&A sites that do open questions.

Comment: @Elemtilas I haven't checked long enough what all these forums are about, that's why I haven't answered officially. Now, if you know the sites in-depth and are confident they answer Louise's problem, take my place and answer :).

Comment: Brainstorming can be done in WB SE chat. There are no restrictions on brainstorming there, though _attendence_ may be diappointin.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest Yahoo! Answers, but I found out it got the axe many years ago.

You are stuck with Reddit and Quora. They both will take any kind of question, from "who would win in a fight between Spiderman and a Warhammer 40K space marine" to "What is your fondest memory you have as a [insert random perversion here]?"

Be aware, though, that exactly due to this permissiveness, the quality of the answers you will get may be lacking. You will hardly get a direct answer, much less one that is about whatever you have asked.